# Check if string contains domains in addition to URL's

Tags: php, regex

I have the following function which checks if a string of text contains a URL beginning with `http://` or `https://` and then wraps it in `<a>` tags, however I need it to also be able to recognize domains (links without http or https in them) like:

```
www.google.com
google.com
```

Here's the function I have:

```
function wrapLinks($content) {
     return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $content);
}
```

I have no idea how I would go about doing this which is why I'm in need of your help.

Comment: This will become a problem if.the text looks like.this; you would.get false positives.

Comment: Just add `?` to make the protocol optional `((f|ht)tps?://)?`

Comment: @Jack What if I included in the regex a list of the most common domain extensions (.com, .co, etc)?

Comment: @HamZa That works great, but if it's just a domain (`google.com`), how can I append `http://` in the link's href?

Comment: @user3871006: then you will get not a list of domains but a subset of domains, still with false positives

Comment: @user3871006 use `preg_replace_callback()`. You can check if group N exists and manipulate the output

Comment: @HamZa Never mind, I just did `<a href="http://$4">$1</a>`. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @faintsignal But if the URL is in the middle of a string, for example: `Hello www.google.com World!`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will help you : http://www.phpro.org/examples/URL-to-Link.html

You just have to be sure it's realy an url with `filter_var($supposed_url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);`

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php for more infos

Hope it helped you !